# One WordPress in multiple /subfolders

Tags: wordpress, zend-framework, .htaccess

Is it possible to have one WP instance run domain.com/articles and domain.com/tips while the rest of the site would be run by Zend Framework?

Comment: Are you wanting separate instances of WP in each of your folders /articles and /tips, or are you wanting one install for both of those URIs?

Answer (score 0):

What you could do is setup a Wordpress MU site. have the install on domain.com/articles and domain.com/tips and then the rest of the site shouldn't cause any problems.

The only downside is that you basically have two sites for two sections of your site. I just did a Wordpress MU build and it got a little tricky but in the end it all worked and its pretty easy to update, just an extra click or two.

Comment: I don't think WP MU can do this. You can install MU in domain.com/articles and have a second blog at domain.com/articles/tips, a third at domain.com/articles/blog3, etc. but the sub-folders all need to be under the install sub-folder.

Answer (score 0):

You can install Worpress in your root domain. Make the homepage of the Wordpress install the current homepage of your website with all of the links, layouts, and original site subfolders preserved. Then just have Wordpress take care of the other URLs that you defined above, making sure not to create any Wordpress directories that conflict with the current site directories.